# getRespondentEmail() returning my email not the Form responder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am on a Google domain and am trying to extract the form respondents email (which is automatically collected as they have to be signed in to fill out the form)

but the result is that I keep getting my email returned instead of the form respondent?

This is code that is contained within the given form, hence using

var form = FormApp.getActiveForm()

but I cant work out why I am getting my own email every time?

```js
function GetRespondersEmail(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  
  var responses=form.getResponses();
/// this will give you all responses of your form as an array////

///iterate the array to get respondent email id///

for(var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++){
   var emailTo = responses[i].getRespondentEmail();
  
  Logger.log('emailTo = '+emailTo);
  return emailTo;
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getRespondentEmail() :

Gets the email address of the person who submitted this response, if the Form.setCollectEmail(collect) setting is enabled.

Did you set Form.setCollectEmail(collect) to true ?

NB: This feature is available only for forms created by users of Google Apps for Business, Google Apps for Education, or Google Apps for Your Domain. Email addresses for other types of Google accounts cannot be collected. For forms created with other Google accounts, this method throws a scripting exception.

Here is the edit:
I changed a bit your code. The problem is you return a value on your loop, so you never finish your loop, and return only the e-mail of the first response.

```
function GetRespondersEmail(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var emailTo = []
  var responses=form.getResponses();
/// this will give you all responses of your form as an array////

///iterate the array to get respondent email id///

for(var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++){
   emailTo[i] = responses[i].getRespondentEmail();     
}
  Logger.log('emailTo = '+emailTo);
  return emailTo;
};
```

I tried this and seems to answer your needs.

Comment: Ahh super...yes I see now, awesome!  Would you know how I would isolate the users email of the form currently being submitted or re-submitted with ammendments?

Comment: @LMS Unfortunately, this script gets the value from the "email" field, where you can enter any value, including a dummy one.
How to determine the real email, the question remains open.

Comment: Well, long time ago I answered this, didn't see the second question. In this case, i'm not sure, indeed, that you can check email for the current respondent.
Nevertheless, in the example above, you get an answer to this Google_Form, which is a google Object, that uses the email of the respondent that answered the Form. It's a native function that gets the email associated to the account responding the form, it's not about a user field.

Answer (score 8):

Ok so lesson learnt for me, what I am trying to do is access the single email address of the user filling in the form . So it turns out I can fully replace the above function with the function onFormSubmit()
ie

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
   var emailTo = e.response.getRespondentEmail();
}
```

Unless I am overlooking something this is far simpler than I was trying above.